# How to tell style tag to get property from class?

Tags: javascript, css

I know this question seems strange but you'll see it is not so difficult to understand.

I am writing this rules with javascript:

```
    var cap_style = {
        all:'initial',
        'display':'block',
        'max-width':'100%',
        'position':'relative',
        'height':'auto',
        'margin':'0 auto'
    };
```

I used the rule `all:'initial'` to get rid of the css that the element may get from the css of the page. The problem comes when, after that I want to add a class to transition it:

```
.transitioned{
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

As you'll see, the class doesn't affect because `all:initial` sets it again to: `transition: initial`.

As you can see, I'm overriding part of the all:initial properties, for example, I override display, max-width and position. So the question is:

**Would it be possible to override the transition property to make it inherit from the class?**

If possible, it would be something like:

```
    var cap_style = {
        all:'initial',
        'display':'block',
        (...)
        'transition':'super'
    };
```

Comment: Which language in JavaScript is this? `:O` I mean plug-in.

Comment: @PraveenKumar No plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `!important`

```
.transitioned{
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease !important;
  transition: height 1s ease !important;
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I thought of this before but I don't use important too much and I thought !important could only override stylesheet properties from stylesheet properties and style properties from style properties. But I was completly wrong!